# Допустимость нулевого байта в JS-коде

Tags: javascript

Допустимо ли наличие байта 0x00 в JS-коде? Например, выполнение `eval(String.fromCharCode(97,61,55,59,0));` в FF, Opera, Chrome свежих версий приводит к ошибке. А в WScript микрософтовском ошибок нет. Кто прав?

Comment: WScript - это не совсем javascript. В хроме вроде работает, кстати. К какой ошибке приводит?

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" хром выдает. То что WScript - не JS, это понятно. Но вот хочется понять: в JS такое может быть или нет?

Comment: [похожий вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/no-visible-cause-for-unexpected-token-illegal) но про другой символ. Судя по всему реализация от MS, включая EDGE и возможно IE просто отбрасывают нулевой символ в конце. При этом в самой спецификации особых упоминаний данного символа нет. В исходном коде может использоваться любой символ из UTF-16. Но при этом, использование спецсимволов вне строк весьма ограничено.

Comment: В строке этот символ допустим, а вот в коде это неизвестный зверь аки цифра после `var`, поэтому и ошибка.

Comment: @Grundy Похоже у MS он допустим не только в конце скрипта, но и не в любом месте тоже...

Answer (score 1):

Допустим внутри строки и в комментариях

```js
var x="/*\0*/console.log('hel\0lo')";
console.log(x)
eval(x);
eval(String.fromCharCode(97,61,55,59,47,47,0));
console.log(a)
```